# Clustering unbalanced dataset

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, anomaly-detection, outlier

The data I am working on has some really large price values and some really small values. What I did was first perform feature bagging on the data and got them labelled to (0,1) and then did Clustering on the data along with the labels found in the previous task.

Is this a right way to go?

Comment: Since clustering algorithms are very sensitive to scaling and tend to have issues with non-continuous attributes and attributes of different types I'd assume you are just making things worse.

Comment: "Is this a right way to go?" Probably depends on your data and on what you want to achieve. There may be data where this is exactly the right thing. Maybe you could specify a bit more, how the data is distributed and also specify what your goals are?

Answer (score 2):

What you could try is to make a transformation of the price data, i.e. log(price). By doing so, very large values become smaller. The data is more "harmonic" after the transformation.